# Hub Control Pagination in UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, xaml, pagination, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am using Hub control in UWP (Universal Windows 10 Application) because it more efficient than FlipView and Pivot, but I found the Hub Control in UWP does not support Pagination feature, its just supporting continuously scrolling .

I would to add Pagination feature to Hub Controls by using XAML and C#

```
<Hub x:Name="hub">
<HubSection>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>   
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>

<HubSection>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>   
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the collection item source of HubSection, so when you scroll to a section, you check the position of current item in the source collection and decide to load more when needed.

Comment: How , could you please provide me the c# code or xaml code ?

Comment: Sorry, it could take more of my time and effort, I can not promise anything, but if I find time I will post it here.